# MySQL query from two tables with multiple joining

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables, example - `category & items.`

```
 1. category table has two fields- cat_id, cat_name.
 2. items table has 4 fields field1, field2, field3, field4 which value
    is cat_id.
```

Now, I need to print `cat_name` instead of cat_id in each row.

How can I do that? What will be the MySQL query?

For more info please, have a look here-
Url: http://smartmux.com/demo_roundflat/admin/
username: test
password: test

Comment: First look at joins and try them if you feel any problem then ask here

Comment: Thanks to all for reply. I'm facing problem because every fields (field1, field2, field3, field4) data of my items table are coming from category table. Now, I'm confused how can I join them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right you can do something like this:

```
SELECT items.*, c1.cat_name, c2.cat_name, c3.cat_name, c4.cat_name
FROM items
LEFT JOIN category AS c1 ON c1.cat_id = items.field1
LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c2.cat_id = items.field1
LEFT JOIN category AS c3 ON c3.cat_id = items.field1
LEFT JOIN category AS c4 ON c4.cat_id = items.field1;
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks @D. Kasipovic, your idea worked with a little changes. SELECT items.*, c1.cat_name AS new1, c2.cat_name AS new2, c3.cat_name AS new3, c4.cat_name AS new4
FROM items
LEFT JOIN category AS c1 ON c1.cat_id = items.field1
LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c2.cat_id = items.field2
LEFT JOIN category AS c3 ON c3.cat_id = items.field3
LEFT JOIN category AS c4 ON c4.cat_id = items.field4;

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and your query should be like this :

```
"select t1.*, t2.cat_name FROM table1 as t1 JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.cat_id=t2.cat_id";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm confused here "t1.cat_id=t2.cat_id". My t1 has 4 field related with t2 (t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3, t1.field4). Then, what should be the joining?

Comment: NO that should be common field of both of your table and which is `cat_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id as cat_name  from category as c , items as i where c.id=i.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    category.cat_name
FROM
    category
        JOIN
    items ON category.cat_id = items.field4
```

Comment: Please, have a look here http://smartmux.com/demo_roundflat/admin/  username: test, password: test.   Here exam1, exam2, exam3, exam4 are displaying category id. I need to print category name here. These 4 fields are related with category table.